# How to prove $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{it \omega} dt = 2 \pi \delta(\omega)$

Tags: integration

So I was learning fourier transform then i want to try compute the transform of $\cos(2\pi t)$, I know that it would give delta functions but when i do the math i did not get how the following integral gives delta function. Can someone explain the math to me? Thanks in advence.

My calculations : https://i.stack.imgur.com/01uuT.jpg

Comment: Did you study the Fourier transform and its inverse?

Comment: you cannot prove something that is not true. As stated the integral is clearly divergent

Comment: Yes i know that the integral is divergent but so do you take it as it and say it equals delta function and that is it?

Comment: I tried to study forward fourier transform as far as i know the fourier of a cos(wt) has two delta function but i couldnt understand how we call this divergent integral delta function.

Answer (score 1):

One needs to go into the theory of Fourier transforms of distributions to give the equality a meaning and to show it.

The [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) $\hat{f}$ of a function $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ is defined by
$$\hat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, e^{i\omega t} \, dt.$$

This transfers to [(tempered) distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform), for example
$$\hat{\delta}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(t) \, e^{i\omega t} \, dt = 1.$$

Now there is a theorem saying that
$$\hat{\hat{f}}(s) = 2\pi \, f(-s).$$

Using this we get
$$2\pi \, \delta(\omega) = \hat{\hat{\delta}}(\omega) = \hat{1}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i\omega t} \, dt.$$

Comment: Okay. This made everything clear. Thank you so much.